# PHP does not work properly in Android WebView

Tags: php, android, session, android-studio, android-webview

I created a simple app in android studio using WebView. The WebView element connected to a mobile website. When I login, some sessions like `user` and `id` are created to make the app work properly. Depending on the values of these sessions, information in a list is shown. But, when I login to the mobile application using the same credentials, it looks like some of the sessions are not created. When I echo'ed the sessions, they are simply not shown.

Some time ago I faced this problem too. Because I had to design the list-items, I hardcoded them. When I finished designing them, I replaced the hardcoded with the old function, and it worked! For a short time tho, after rebooting my device the old problem (as described) appeared again.

Comment: PHP is a server technology. It will not care if you use a webView or a browser. (unless you code specifically.)

So I doubt PHP is to blame here.

Comment: Yeah I know that, but how come the app will work in the browser version, and not in the app version? The answer to that question is what I am really looking for.

Comment: Maybe you don't have cookies enabled in your webview?

Comment: Okay, I am going to try that. Updating in a minute.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. The website is working fine on the browser but sessions are not working in webview. Do you find any solution?